# Blank page after logging in using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code of the homepage where there is a login form:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['fb'])){
    echo $_SESSION['fb'];
    session_destroy();
}
?>


<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#818181>
<center><img src=logo.png>
<br>

<img src=voterslogin.png><br>
<a href=voterregister.php><font style='font-family:Century Gothic' size=2>Register</a><br>


<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="login" size=11  style="background-image:url(field.png); border: 2px;  "><br>
<input type="password" name="password" size=11 style="background-image:url(field.png); border: 2px;  "><br>
<input type="image" src="submit.png" alt="Submit button" name="submit"><br>
</form>
____________________________________________________
<br>

<img src=text1.png><br>
<a href=mayor.html><img src=menu1.gif></a><img src=bullet.png><a href=vicemayor.html><img src=menu22.gif></a><img src=bullet.png><a href=senator.html><img src=menu3.gif></a>
<img src=bullet.png><a href=congressman.html><img src=menu4.gif></a><br><a href=councilor.html><img src=menu5.png></a><img src=bullet2.png><a href=partylist.html><img src=menu6.gif></a>
<br>
____________________________________________________
<br><br><br>
<a href=adminlogin.php><img src=login.png></a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the logincheck file:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('voters');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbvoter WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['voter_id'] = $row[0];
            header('Location: ballot.php');
        }else{
            $_SESSION['fb'] = '<p style="color: red">Invalid Username/Password!</p>';
            header('Location: home.php');
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['fb'] = '<p style="color: red">Fill in all fields!</p>';
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
}


?>
```

I checked first if the query actually runs on mysql. IT works. There is a result if I correctly enter the username and password. But when you login, even if the username and pass is correct or not, it just goes to a blank page with login.php in the addressbar.

Why is that?

Comment: A blank page normally means that there's an error in your PHP code - is there anything in the server's error log? How about if you turn on PHP's error reporting? Does anything get output there?

Comment: Yes, maybe it's php error as @andrewsi said,turn on error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Usually a blank page means there's a syntax error somewhere in your script. Have you checked the PHP error log? (edit: you all are too fast)

Comment: Ok. I just checked out the isset on the login.php. Turns out the submit button on the home isn't recognized. I changed it to a default button and not an image. It worked. Why is that?

<input type="image" src="submit.png" name="submit"/><br>

Comment: That's because you can't submit a form using an image (the name attribute doesn't mean anything) without a little JavaScript. Forms only recognize <input type="submit" />.

An easy way around this is to give the form an ID and give the image the attribute `onclick="document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot see any `header('Location:login.php')` in you login check file, so assuming that the check file itself is login.php.
If the page is blank, it means there has either been no output or an error that terminated the script. First check if error reporting is on in your php configuration.

Your input type=image name=submit, has no value, and is **not available as $_POST**, so change the start of the code to

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
$username = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//code continues here

}
```

one suggestion, never use such unstandard methods like type=image, it is better to use **type=submit** with an image background and proper positioning.

Comment: I already got it. I just dont like the type=submit cause it doesnt look good.

Comment: Me neither. If you want to stick with traditional forms, I suggest using <button> and attaching a JavaScript onclick handler to submit it.

Comment: use type=submit and then css to style it the way you wish, really you can do whatever you want, change width, height, background image. anything!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you are using header() you always need to specify where is the code is staring by placing ob_start() like so:

```
<?php
ob_start();

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['fb'])){
    echo $_SESSION['fb'];
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But that wasnt the error. I just checked out the isset on the login.php. Turns out the submit button on the home isn't recognized. I changed it to a default button and not an image. It worked. Why is that? <input type="image" src="submit.png" name="submit"/><br>

Comment: That's just a hack and **not a real solution** to the possible problem.

Comment: @PeeHaa I see. But why is that putting an image on a submit button didn't work?

Comment: no hes checking $_POST['submit'] which is type=image, and is not recieved without any value.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using PDO over mysql_ functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
PHP's manual provides a good insight in getting started with it.

Also, from what I can see, your code is injection vulnerable. Make sure you sanitize before using this code in production.

Comment: I admit it isn't - sorry. Whenever I see usage of mysql_ I always get a little tense.